# Using fminsearch to perform distribution fitting

Tags: matlab, probability, curve-fitting, data-fitting, fminsearch

Suppose I have a set of univariate data held in the array `errors`.

I would like to fit a PDF to my observed data distribution.

My PDF is defined in a function `poissvmwalkpdf`, whose definition line looks like this:

```
function p = poissvmwalkpdf(theta, mu, kappa, xi)
```

Here, `theta` is the error (the variable for which values in `errors` are instances), and `mu`, `kappa`, and `xi` are parameters of the PDF for which I want to find the best fit using maximum-likelihood estimation.  This function returns the probability density at a given value of `theta`.

Given all this, how would I use `fminsearch` to find the values for `mu`, `kappa`, and `xi` that best fit my observed `errors`?  The `fminsearch` documentation doesn't make this clear.  None of the examples in the documentation are examples of distribution fitting.

Note: The tutorial [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/curve-fitting-and-distribution-fitting.html) clearly describes what distribution fitting is (as distinguished from curve fitting), but the example given does not use `fminsearch`.

Comment: Trick question: why not use what the tutorial uses for distribution fitting?:)

Comment: There is no unique fit for such data. Choices must be made in how a fit is done and generic fitting methods don't take into account that the data is assumed to be sampled from a known distribution. The most common distribution fitting methods are based on [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) (and minimizing the negative log likelihood). You *could* use `fminsearch` and you might get something decent, but it probably won't return the statistically most likely parameters.

Comment: @horchler you can interpret my question as, "how would i use `fminsearch` to derive an MLE fit between my PDF and my data?"  you seem to be arguing that `fminsearch` cannot do that, but it's a generic minimization function.  it can minimize a negative log likelihood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of using `fminsearch` to obtain maximum likelihood estimates (as requested in the comments):

```
function mle_fit_minimal

n       = 100;
% for reproducibility
rng(333)
% generate dummy data
errors  = normrnd(0,1,n,1);

par0    = [1, 1];
[par_hat, nll] = fminsearch(@nloglike, par0)

% custom pdf
    function p = my_pdf(data, par)
        mu      = par(1);
        sigma   = par(2);
        p       = normpdf(data, mu, sigma);
    end

% negative loglikelihood function -- note that the parameters must be passed in a 
% single argument (here called par).
    function nll = nloglike(par)
        nll     = -sum(log(my_pdf(errors, par)));
    end
end
```

After formulating the likelihood function (or negative loglikelihood) it is just a simple optimization.

[image]

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks.  users with the same question i had might also wish to consult [this blog post](http://randomanalyses.blogspot.com/2011/11/fitting-probability-distributions-to.html).