# Maximum likelihood estimate custom pdf in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a custom pdf that has 3 parameters (X,n,k), where X represents the data (vector) and n,k are two scalars. I want to calculate the mle for this custom pdf, so I wrote this in matlab:

```
custpdf=@(X,n,k)custompdf(length(X),n,k)
phat =mle(X,'pdf',custpdf,'start',[n0,k0])
```

But I get this error:

```
Too many input arguments.
```

I searched for an answer, but couldn't find one. What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you guys.

Comment: @whuber: Maybe moving this to SO will be more appropriate.  (I would vote to close as belong to another SE website if possible)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the *full* error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fminsearch to perform distribution fitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951934/using-fminsearch-to-perform-distribution-fitting)